# Accessing the --default-remote-prefix within the Snakefile

Tags: snakemake

When I run snakemake on the google life sciences executor, I run something like:

```
snakemake  --google-lifesciences --default-remote-prefix my_bucket_name  --preemption-default 10 --use-conda
```

Now, `my_bucket_name` is going to get added to all of the input and output paths.

BUT for *reasons* I need to recreate the full path within the Snakefile code and therefore I want to be able to access whatever is passed to `--default-remote-prefix` within the code

Is there a way to do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> I want to be able to access whatever is passed to --default-remote-prefix within the code

You can use the [workflow](https://snakemake.readthedocs.io/en/stable/_modules/snakemake/workflow.html) object like:

```
print(workflow.default_remote_prefix) # Will print my_bucket_name in your example

rule all:
    input: ...
```

I'm not 100% sure if the `workflow` object is supposed to be used by the user or if it's private to snakemake and if so it could be changed in the future without warning. But I think it's ok, I use  `workflow.basedir` all the time to get the directory where the Snakefile sits.

Alternatively you could parse the `sys.argv` list but I think that this is more hacky.

---

Another option:

```
bucket_name=foo
snakemake --default-remote-prefix $bucket_name --config bucket_name=$bucket_name ...
```

then use `config["bucket_name"]` within the code to get the value `foo`. But I still prefer the `workflow` solution.